# How to create new column with header name as value based on specific condition of multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine I have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4],
                   "CLASS A":[np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   "CLASS B":[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   "CLASS C":[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
                   "DEPTH":[12, 31, 45, 66, 32, 46]})

df
Out[4]: 
   ID  CLASS A  CLASS B  CLASS C  DEPTH
0   1      NaN      NaN      NaN     12
1   1      1.0      NaN      NaN     31
2   2      NaN      NaN      NaN     45
3   3      NaN      NaN      1.0     66
4   3      NaN      NaN      NaN     32
5   4      NaN      NaN      NaN     46
```

I would like to create a new column (df["FILTER"]) with the name of the column as value where I have the number 1, but only looking to the columns (CLASS A, CLASS B and CLASS C). So my final dataframe should look like this:

```
 ID  CLASS A  CLASS B  CLASS C  DEPTH     FILTER
0   1      NaN      NaN      NaN     12     NaN
1   1      1.0      NaN      NaN     31     CLASS A
2   2      NaN      NaN      NaN     45     NaN
3   3      NaN      NaN      1.0     66     CLASS C
4   3      NaN      NaN      NaN     32     NaN
5   4      NaN      NaN      NaN     46     NaN
```

Anyone could help me?

Comment: is it possible for 2 columns to have the same value? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the columns and [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to get the header:

```
df['FILTER'] = df.filter(like='CLASS').idxmax(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   ID  CLASS A  CLASS B  CLASS C  DEPTH   FILTER
0   1      NaN      NaN      NaN     12      NaN
1   1      1.0      NaN      NaN     31  CLASS A
2   2      NaN      NaN      NaN     45      NaN
3   3      NaN      NaN      1.0     66  CLASS C
4   3      NaN      NaN      NaN     32      NaN
5   4      NaN      NaN      NaN     46      NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, before will be great read about idxmax:

```
class_columns = ["CLASS A", "CLASS B", "CLASS C"]
df['FILTER'] = df[class_columns].idxmax(axis=1)
df['FILTER'] = df['FILTER'].where(df[class_columns].max(axis=1)==1, np.nan)
```